# How to access local file in Flask?

Tags: flask, routes

I want to access the local file using a hyperlink from the web using Flask. My file directory and what I have tried is as follows.

File directory:

```
-Flask
     -static/
         --some js
     -template/
         --some HTML
     -logs/
         --log1.log
         --log2.log
         --...
     app.py
```

I access the file in HTML as

```
 localhost:port/logs/log1.log
```

But the web gives me a 404.

How could I access the file? I am not very sure about the route in Flask. Could you give me some reference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [send_from_directory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_from_directory) function in flask to send static files
This might help you

```
@app.route('/logs/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory("/logs/",
                               filename, as_attachment=True)
```